# Can not catch exception in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

```
class Collector
  class ContentNotFound < Exception
  end

  class DuplicateContent < Exception
  end
end

begin
  raise Collector::ContentNotFound.new
rescue
  puts "catch"
end
```

When I run the script I don't get "catch" message I see error:

```
lib/collector/exception.rb:10:in `<main>': Collector::ContentNotFound (Collector::ContentNotFound)
```

Why? How Can I catch my exceptions without typing their classes in rescue?

Comment: You don't need the `.new` - you can just have `raise Collector::ContentNotFound`. All part of ruby's magic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to catch those exceptions as-is, use:

```
rescue Exception
```

The bare `rescue` keyword only catches derivatives of `StandardError` (with good reason).

However, a better solution is to have your custom exceptions derive from `StandardError`.

For an explanation on why this is so, see [this section](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html#S2) of the PickAxe.

Comment: Reason for downvote? It answers the question, and provides a better solution based on ruby best practices?

Comment: Downvode was not by me. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Jacon: There's currently one upvote and no downvotes. When I first read your answer, I briefly downvoted it, because it was advocating `rescue Exception`, but cancelled the downvote when I saw you mentioning that the custom exception should derive from `StandardError`.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies it. It is worth noting that `rescue Exception` is bad practice, so I'll add that in.

Answer (score 3):

See this post for an explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383229/common-programming-mistakes-for-ruby-developers-to-avoid/2019170#2019170

Basically, you can do

```
class ContentNotFound < RuntimeError
end
```

to catch that without having to specify an exception class in the `rescue` statement.